# Google map showing Double markers on mapclick in Google Map V3 but I want one at a particular point on mapclick

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, phonegap-build

[image]

Whenever I add an marker and  calculate the route on Map Click the second marker it shows two marker on a single icon as shown in the image.
I want only one marker (which is A) in one location
  Code Snippet

```
var map, lat, lng;
var count = 1;
var markers = [],
    content_marker;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService;
var pos_source, pos_desti;

// First Function

function onDeviceReady() {
    var height = $(window).outerHeight(true);
    $("#googleMap").css("height", height);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    });
}

// GPS Success

function onSuccess(position) {

    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;

    /*
     * for ( var j = 0; j <= 10; j++) { setInterval(function() { lat++; lng++; },
     * 5000);
     */

    var mapProp = {

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        event.latLng;

        placeMarker(event.latLng);

    });

    /*
     * Auto Complete Search Box Starts var input =
     * (document.getElementById('pac-input')); var input1 =
     * (document.getElementById('pac-input1'));
     * 
     * var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input)); var searchBox1 =
     * new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input1));
     */

    // Auto Complete Search Box Ends }

    // Placing Marker

    function placeMarker(location) {
        if (count == 1 || count == 2) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                marker.setMap(null);
                count--;
            });

            if (count == 1) {

                pos_source = location;
                content_marker = 'Source';
                // marker.setMap(null);

            }
            if (count == 2) {

                // setInterval(function() {
                pos_desti = location;
                content_marker = 'Destination';
                // marker.setMap(null);
                calcRoute();
                // }, 3000);

            }

            // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            // var x;
            // if (confirm("Remove Markers!") == true) {
            // x = "You pressed OK!";
            // } else {
            // x = "You pressed Cancel!";
            // }
            //
            // });

            count++;

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: content_marker
            });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

        }

    }

    // Calculating Distance
    function computeTotalDistance(result) {
        var total = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {

            total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        }
        total = total / 1609.34;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' miles';
    }

    function deleteMarkers() {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // Calculating route
    function calcRoute() {

        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        alert("Creating Shortest Path !!!");

        var request = {
            origin: pos_source,
            destination: pos_desti,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());


                deleteMarkers();
            }
        });

    }

    // On GPS Error
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

Comment: Where's the closing `}` for the `onSuccess` function?  Right now the code here hasn't got one, and all subsequent functions are part of that function.  Line 45 is just `event.latLng;` - what's that meant to be doing?

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is you're getting directions, which renders markers on its start and end points.  And you're adding your own marker.  You can simply prevent the directions renderer from displaying markers.  Add `suppressMarkers: true` to its options:

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});
```

Comment: What if the user want the directionsDisplay marker but don't want the placed marker ?

Comment: just remove where you create the marker:  `var marker = new google.maps.Marker`